# Are closed subsets of Sobolev spaces closed in L^2?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it true that a closed set of $L^p_k(U)$ (with $p >1$, $k\geq 0 $) is closed in $L^2(U)$? (assuming it is contained in $L^2(U)$)

Is this true if $U$ is instead a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? and if $U$ is compact and $p=2$?

Comment: You mean closed in $L^2$ or in $L^p$?

Comment: I mean in $L^2$ but I don't know the answer for $L^p$ either..

Comment: The entire space $L^p_k(U)$ itself is closed (in itself), but not closed in $L^p(U)$ or (if it is contained in $L^2(U)$) in $L^2(U)$.

Comment: why is not closed in $L^p(U)$? or in $L^2(U)$ (when is contained here)?

Comment: In fact $L^p_k$ is dense in $L^p$ (as are the $C^\infty$ functions with compact support.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. One example was already given: for $k\ge 1$, the Sobolev space $L_k^p$  is a closed subset of itself, but is a dense subset of $L^2$, because it contains smooth functions, and smooth functions are dense in $L^2$.

An example of different nature is given in $L^p_1(0, 1)$ by the sequence 
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1-nx,\quad &0\le x\le \frac{1}{n}
\\ 0, \quad & x>\frac1n \end{cases} 
$$
This sequence has no limit points in $L^p_1$ norm, and therefore $\{f_n\}$ is a closed set. But it is not a closed set in any $L^p$ for any $1\le p<\infty$ since $f_n\to 0$ in $L^p$ norm.